# Python: Having issues returning the whole dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having issues returning the whole dictionary from my code.  I currently have not worked on the second function so that can be ignored.  I'm just trying to make sure the first function works first.

This is what I have for my code right now.

```
def disease_to_code_dictionary(  ) :
    """ Function returns a dictionary with disease names as keys and
      ICD 10 codes as values. """

    diseases = {}

    infile = open("ICD10.txt","r")
    header_row = infile.readline() # skip the header row

    for line in infile :

        cells = line.split("\t") # split by the tab character
        if len(cells) >= 2 : # only if the line had a tab
            code = cells[0]
            disease = cells[1]
            disease = disease.lower() # lowercase
            disease = disease.replace("\"","") # remove all double quotes

            diseases[disease] = code

            return diseases
                
    infile.close()

    return list(diseases.items())


    # The program should give the code if the disease name exists
    # otherwise say "Disease name does not exist.".
    def query_disease_to_code() :
        """ Interactive function to query code from disease name. """
        d = disease_to_code_dictionary() # disease to code dictionary
        
       #query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
        #while query != "q" :
         #   query = query.lower() # lowercase
            # complete here
          #  query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
    
        print(d)
        
    
    query_disease_to_code()
```

Output: {'cholera due to vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae': 'A000'}
The text I'm reading from has a ton more lines but this the only one showing.

Comment: Perhaps you want to create your dictionary before the loop, instead of creating a new empty dictionary each turn through the loop.

Comment: Hi there, could you please provide an example of what your input file looks like and what your expected output looks like? Also, have you considered using `pandas`?

Comment: it is an assignment from my professor so I work off what she gives me

Comment: and you might want to `disease = desease.strip()` away spaces and newlines from it

Comment: @user6386471 the output right now is outputting the dictionary of the disease name and codes, its a little long so i'd rather not put it on here

Comment: It seems `disease={}` Should be `diseases={}`.. right?

Comment: @adira bargil yes i did fix that just a while ago

Comment: Thanks @ChamongLo, maybe you could provide a small sample of the expected output which you can put together manually? This will help people to know how to help out. Also, the first few lines of the input file would be very helpful.

Comment: @user6386471 okay done, i included the output, and in my code there are only 2 functions but I took out the second function because it's not relevant to my current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in your dict name. Second I would recommend to split these two functionalities (Reading the file and parsing the text):

```
def disease_to_code_dictionary( file_text ) :
    
        diseases = {}

        for line in file_text.split("\n")[1:] :

         
            cells = line.split("\t")
            
            if len(cells) >= 2 : 
                code = cells[0]
                disease = cells[1]
                disease = disease.lower() 
                disease = disease.replace("\"","") 

                diseases[disease] = code


        return diseases

txt = """Code\tDisease
1\tMalaria
2\tEbola
3\tYellow Fever
"""
```

Now when I run this code on txt it returns as expected:

```
{'malaria': '1', 'ebola': '2', 'yellow fever': '3'}
```

Comment: thanks i got this part figured out now, but I have a different issue now.  I updated my post

Comment: If you have a new question, make a new post